# Need to Use \Z in Rails Routing Constraint Regex But Get an Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I need to allow a route to match the following four formats:

- foo
- foo.json
- foo.bar
- foo.bar.json

If a route ends with ".json", just the part before that should be matched, so the only possible matches for those four examples would be "foo" and "foo.bar".

I came up with the following regular expression: `/.*?(?=\.json|\Z)/`, but it doesn't work because Rails does not allow you to use `\Z` in a route constraint:

> Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements: `/.*?(?=\.json|\Z)/`

Is there a way around this or another regular expression I could use?

Comment: Make the `.json` optional.. `(?:\.json)?`

Comment: @LeeJarvis what would that look like as a complete regex? I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @RossPenman You meant something like [this](http://rubular.com/r/veo8DawTmI) ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV yeah, like that, but the match result can't include the .json because Rails doesn't take the match groups into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating two different routes, one with JSON on the end and one without, both using different regular expressions. So where previously the route had looked like this.

```
get ':foo', to: 'foo#bar', constraints: { foo: /.*?(?=\.json|\Z)/ }
```

It now looks like this:

```
get ':foo.json', to: 'foo#bar', constraints: { foo: /.*?(?=\.json)/ }, format: :json
get ':foo',      to: 'foo#bar', constraints: { foo: /.*?/ }
```

Comment: in rails 2 use :requirements => {:id => /[A-Z0-9]{1,}([\/_-]{1}[A-Z0-9]{1,})*/i}

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will match the entire string and capture only the part you need

```
(.*?)(?:\.json)?$
```

http://regex101.com/r/sM6rD0

This regex will match and capture only the part you need

```
^((?:.(?!\.json$))*(?:$|.))
```

http://rubular.com/r/SdtEDiWPRX

The second regex is overly complex though and I highly doubt you need your match and your capture to be exactly the same. But then again, I don't know much about rails :)

Comment: I need the result of the expression to not include the .json and this one does. This does match the part before it, but Rails doesn't take that into account. It uses only the string like "foo.bar.json".

Comment: it shouldn't capture .json, because the capture group starts with ?:. This ought to work: try it.

Comment: Perhaps Ruby regular expressions work differently, because this example doesn't work: http://rubular.com/r/IZ5PJT33iI

Comment: Seems to work fine with ruby! Look at those matches in rubular. Isn't that exactly what you wanted?

Comment: there is a difference between a capture and a match. It matches the whole string, but captures only the part before .json or, if there is no .json at the end, captures the whole string.

Comment: Rails only seems to use the match, though, so I need an expression that doesn't match the .json.

Comment: dude :) Ruby regex is based on the PCRE engine which supports the whole lot. The regexes I've presented to you will do the job; trust me. Now it's your job to find out how to use them properly :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make your own object which defines a .matches? method. That combined with @mrhobo's regex should work.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Answer (score 0):

You need restrict not url, but only format this way:

```
  get 'foo', format: /bar|json|bar\.json/, to: 'main#foo'
```

Format will be available in controller as `params[:format]`

Comment: I'm not trying to restrict formats, I'm trying to match everything before the .json. .bar is not a format.

Comment: You write in first paragraph "four formats" - I did not understand you. Ok, I have solution for you, I'll give it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so trivial, if you want to get arbitrary keys:

```
get ":foo(.:bar)", to: 'main#foo', bar: /(?!json$|html$)[^\.]*/
```

One thing you should concern, is that `:bar` cannot be `json` (or any other appropriate format)

In you controller you'll have `params[:foo]` and `params[:bar]`

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear, but foo and bar are meant to be arbitrary strings. What I really want to do is match and string before .json, which is an optional token, without using anchors.